# python Pandas how to remove lines from dataframe based on next lines (in a specific timeframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I am having events in a dataframe of total of 3 columns - identificator, event status and datetime.

```
Identificator   Date    Status
ID1 2021-05-02 19:55:43 OK
ID2 2021-05-02 19:48:01 FAILED
ID3 2021-05-02 19:47:53 OK
ID1 2021-05-03 19:55:43 OK
ID2 2021-05-03 20:48:01 OK
ID3 2021-05-03 19:47:53 OK
ID1 2021-05-04 19:55:43 FAILED
ID1 2021-05-04 20:55:43 OK
ID2 2021-05-04 19:48:01 OK
ID3 2021-05-04 19:47:53 OK
```

I need to delete all lines where the status is failed, but there is another attempt in the next 24 for the same ID.

For example - line 2 should stay, because the next attempt is ~25 hours later.
Line 7 should be deleted, because the next attempt for ID1 is only 1 hour later.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) by grouping the **Date** and **Identificator** values within 24 hrs, and then picking last value for each **Identificator** within a group.

You can also specify a specific time from where to start the **24H** groups by using the `origin` param. By default, it is set to **"start_day"**, which is midnight (*00:00:00*). So to start the 24H intervals from say 3 PM, you can do it like:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='24H', origin='15:00:00'),'Identificator'], as_index=False).agg({'Date':'last', 'Status':'last'})
```

Now to only remove the rows with **'FAILED'** status that later became **'OK'** within *24 hrs*, you can merge this grouped dataframe obtained above with the original, and then drop the rows where ***'FAILED'*** status row was not present in the grouped dataframe.

So do it all as below:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
grouped_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='24H', origin='15:00:00'),'Identificator'], as_index=False).agg({'Date':'last', 'Status':'last'})
df = df.merge(grouped_df, on=['Identificator','Date'], suffixes=('','_grouped'), how="left")
df = df[~((df.Status=='FAILED') & (df.Status_grouped.isna()))].drop('Status_grouped', axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
  Identificator                Date  Status
0           ID1 2021-05-02 19:55:43      OK
1           ID2 2021-05-02 19:48:01  FAILED
2           ID3 2021-05-02 19:47:53      OK
3           ID1 2021-05-03 19:55:43      OK
4           ID2 2021-05-03 20:48:01      OK
5           ID3 2021-05-03 19:47:53      OK
7           ID1 2021-05-04 20:55:43      OK
8           ID2 2021-05-04 19:48:01      OK
9           ID3 2021-05-04 19:47:53      OK
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the time of the day when the 24H chunks are seperated by each other? For example new period to start always from 3PM ?

Comment: Yes you can use `origin` param in `pd.Grouper` for that. You can set `origin='15:00:00'` to start each period from 3 pm.

Comment: I have added the details in answer for this. Have a look.

Comment: This is close to what I need, but I am loosing the information about how many successful attempts are performed in the 24H period, which is important for the statistics.

Comment: OK this can be solved by merging back the result to your original df. I have added the extra code to preserve all successful attempts. Check it now.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First I copied and paste this data into an excel file, and convert its data to column as follows:

[image]

saved and then read the saved excel file with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('excel path')

print(df)

  Identificator                Date  Status
0           ID1 2021-05-02 19:55:43      OK
1           ID2 2021-05-02 19:48:01  FAILED
2           ID3 2021-05-02 19:47:53      OK
3           ID1 2021-05-03 19:55:43      OK
4           ID2 2021-05-03 20:48:01      OK
5           ID3 2021-05-03 19:47:53      OK
6           ID1 2021-05-04 19:55:43  FAILED
7           ID1 2021-05-04 20:55:43      OK
8           ID2 2021-05-04 19:48:01      OK
9           ID3 2021-05-04 19:47:53      OK
```

following I filter the table by id values and calculations in the filtered table. Find the desired to be deleted row, remove that row from the dataframe that is first read.

```
unique_ids=df.Identificator.unique()

for id in unique_ids:
  df2=df[df.Identificator==str(id)]
  df2=df2.reset_index()
  for i in df2.index:
    if df2.Status[i]=="OK":
      pass
    if df2.Status[i]=="FAILED":
      print(df2.Date[i+1]-df2.Date[i])
      timediff=(df2.Date[i+1]-df2.Date[i])
      ashour=timediff.total_seconds()/60/60
      if ashour<24:
        df=df[~(df['Date'] == df2.Date[i])]

print(df)
```

The result is:

```
  Identificator                Date  Status
0           ID1 2021-05-02 19:55:43      OK
1           ID2 2021-05-02 19:48:01  FAILED
2           ID3 2021-05-02 19:47:53      OK
3           ID1 2021-05-03 19:55:43      OK
4           ID2 2021-05-03 20:48:01      OK
5           ID3 2021-05-03 19:47:53      OK
7           ID1 2021-05-04 20:55:43      OK
8           ID2 2021-05-04 19:48:01      OK
9           ID3 2021-05-04 19:47:53      OK
```